# skip error in PL/SQL Oracle database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I use Oracle PL/SQL and need to check is there client with ID in table. (YES or NO).  I made a query to table and it returns row with this ID into `v_klient`. For example, in my table there's no ID with number 2. But I can't compare this, because error "no data found". Need to skip this error and compare with `if` statement and do some actions that I want.

```
DECLARE
    id_kl_original  NUMBER := 2; // this ID
    v_klient klients%rowtype; // Variable for query return
BEGIN
SELECT *
  INTO  v_klient
    FROM klients
      WHERE id_klient=id_kl_original; // query

IF (v_klient IS NULL) THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(' There's no clients with this ID.');
     /* SOME ACTIONS*/
ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_klient.id_klient);
    /* SOME ACTIONS*/
END IF;

END;
```

Comment: I recommend you to use `COUNT()` function rather than your actual solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try it this way:

```
DECLARE
    id_kl_original  NUMBER := 2; // this ID
    v_klient klients%rowtype; // Variable for query return
BEGIN
   BEGIN
      SELECT *
      INTO  v_klient
      FROM klients
      WHERE id_klient=id_kl_original; // query

      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_klient.id_klient);
      /* SOME ACTIONS*/
   EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(' There's no clients with this ID.');
     /* SOME ACTIONS*/
   END;
   /* REST OF PROCEDURE */
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
DECLARE
    id_kl_original  NUMBER := 2; // this ID
    i NUMBER; // Variable for query return
BEGIN
SELECT count(*)
  INTO i
    FROM klients
      WHERE id_klient=id_kl_original; // query

IF (i = 0) THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(' There are no clients with this ID.');
     /* SOME ACTIONS*/
ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_klient.id_klient);
    /* SOME ACTIONS*/
END IF;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the no_data_found exception is cleaner than first executing the query to fetch the number of rows and then executing it again to actually fetch the rows.

```
DECLARE
    id_kl_original  NUMBER := 2; -- this ID
    v_klient klients%rowtype; -- Variable for query return
    v_has_data := true;
BEGIN

    BEGIN
        SELECT *
          INTO  v_klient
            FROM klients
              WHERE id_klient = id_kl_original; -- query
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
            v_has_data := FALSE; 
    END;

    IF v_has_data = FALSE THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('There''s no clients with this ID.');
         /* SOME ACTIONS */
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(v_klient.id_klient);
        /* SOME ACTIONS*/
    END IF;

END;
```